# Excel: Use Cell Range which is saved in a cell for completing a formula in another cell

Tags: excel, reference, formula

[image]

In the above Table i would like to use the range defined in V2 for the formula defined in E2. It should replace the green underlined part of the formula. As you can see there is already the right range in there but it is for flexibility reasons if the range changes so i don't have to change all the formulas which are in E2,F2,G2,... and so on.

The Formula:
    =VLOOKUP("contract index",INDIRECT("'PURCHASING'!"&V2),2,FALSE)

Comment: Just an FYI; one should post the code/formula as text in the question and not as a picture.  The picture should be backup to the text.  It is also helpful to put the data as text in a [MCVE]

Comment: Updated, but to be honest, there was really no need for that in this case of questioning and it was absolutly no problem for Jeeped to answer in 4' without having the formula. Sorry for my rudeness but sometimes this attitude of correcting and decry makes me feel like the internet is no longer a place to ask question and post answers but to be better. would be delighted if we just could grow as a community by helping each other in every way we can

Comment: The request is to help us help you. We can answer quicker an more correctly if we can copy paste instead of recreating what you already have. It makes it easier on us to help you. I was not being rude just informing you of what is helpful. Remember we are all volunteers here and if it saves us times it is appreciated.

Comment: @Scott Carner, i get you, you're totally right about that. i was thinking there would be an easy fix without having to know my formula because it was also a general question how to use a range from another cell in a formula. Sorry about the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
=vlookup("contract index", indirect("'purchasing'!" & v2), 2, false)
```